# PHP Match a string exactly

Tags: php, string, match

```
$check = 'this is a string 111';
if ($check = 'this is a string') {
echo 'perfect match';
} else {
echo 'it did not match up';
}
```

But it returns perfect match everytime instead of it did not match up... I can not seem to get the string to match the case exactly it will only work if part of the string matches up.

If i try to complicate things a little using board code and regex patterns it becomes a nightmare.

```
if ($check = '/\[quote(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/su') {
$spam['spam'] = true;
$spam['error'] .= 'Spam post quote.<br />';
}
```

So if the post only contained quote tags it would be considered spam and ditched but i can not seem to solve it perhaps my patterns are wrong.

Comment: +1 because it's a very real outcome/pitfall of a language that lets you return the value from an assignment.

Comment: @RobAgar this _really_ is debugging 101. Upvotes are for, which you can see when hovering over the upvote button, "useful questions showing research effort". Both don't apply here.

Comment: agree with CodeCaster, this looks like your PHP & general programming level is not on par with the task you've got to solve.IMHO,This place is not made for teaching basic programming nor PHP.

Comment: @CodeCaster - and downvotes are *not* for smacking down beginners.

Comment: It would not be much of a question without a answer.. I'm sorry for my first question if i upset anyone but it is just a personal issue i have been struggling to figure out on my own.

Comment: @C0nw0nk i think he's saying that you need to edit the question to include what you want the code to output...

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `==` not just `=`

```
$check = 'this is a string 111';
if ($check == 'this is a string') {
echo 'perfect match';
} else {
echo 'it did not match up';
}
```

`=` will assign the variable.

`==` will do a loose comparison

`===` will do a strict comparison

See [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more information.

Comment: If you really want to be exact, use the strict comparison (`===`) operator, otherwise the following is true:  `if ('123' == 123)`

Comment: Thanks it did work for my basic string but not when i start complicating things with regex patterns

Comment: Yeah, string comparisons won't work using regex...for that you'd need to do a preg_match - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 4):

For  equality comparison you want the `==` operator. `=` is assignment.

```
if ($check = 'this is a string') {
```

should be

```
if ($check == 'this is a string') {
```

Don't worry, we've all done it. I still do :)

Answer (score 3):

the == comparison operator will work in most cases, but fails to do an exact match in some edge cases*.

Using === operator is best.

```
if ($check === 'this is a string') {
```

An example where == works unexpectedly

```
$check = '2';
if ($check == '          2') {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the assignment operator, `=`, instead of the equality operator `==`.

You need to use

```
if ($check == 'this is a string') {
```

Answer (score 2):

`if ($check = 'this is a string')` assigns the string to `$check` variable which is always defined and thus, returns always true in the if

should be `if ($check == 'this is a string')`

Comment: `which is always defined and thus, returns always true` - not entirely true. If you do `if ($check = 0)` it will evaluate to false. What will actually happen here is that PHP will evaluate the right side of the expression as boolean.

Comment: exact, but as long as you assign a non empty string,it'll evaluate to a true equivalent.

Comment: ...unless the string is `'0'`

Comment: Thanks it did work for my basic string but not when i start complicating things with regex patterns